# Django response redirect on variable url

Tags: django

I'm on a page with a variable url `/emails/edit/32/`, and I want to update the form and refresh the page...how do I issue an HttpResponseRedirect to the current page, which has a variable extension?

My urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^emails/edit/$', 'email_edit'),    # this is the page it is re-directing to
    (r'^emails/edit/(?P<email_id>\d+)/$', 'emails_single'),
)
```

And my views.py is:

```
def emails_single(request, email_id):
    ...(stuff)...
    Email.objects.filter(id=request.POST['id']).update(email=request.POST['email'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('emails_single',args=[email_id]))
```

Update: what it is doing is just chopping off the ending of the URL (even when using the reverse examples). For example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/emails/edit/42/ --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/emails/edit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('emails_single', args=[email_id]))
```

Comment: JamesO: I have updated the question to show what I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

[`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('urlname', args=[1945]))
```